# Regex pattern to check until next set of pattern but exclude it

Tags: regex, groovy

I'm trying to match and keep all the following text (including the numbers) until next set of numbers

```
string = "100 - Generic - Applicable (Prepaid leg) 101 - TFM - N/A 102 - TOPUP - Applicable (Prepaid leg) 103 - Staff - Applicable (Prepaid leg)"
```

my regex below grabs the next set of digits too and breaks the rest as you can see

```
\b(\d{3}.*?\s\d{3})
```

essentially the result should look like this

```
list = ['100 - Generic - Applicable (Prepaid leg)','101 - TFM - N/A','etc','etc']
```

https://regex101.com/r/2QOMzy/1

I'm struggling to tell it to exclude\stop at the last pattern.
I've looked at these, with out success obviously:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43899304/pcre-regex-matching-patterns-until-next-pattern-is-found

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49487978/regex-to-match-pattern-until-next-occurence-of-it

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33249035/regex-match-from-pattern-until-another-pattern

Comment: You need `\b(\d{3}.*?)(?=\s\d{3})` or `\b\d{3}.*?(?=\s\d{3})`. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12083308/3832970) where you can see how to also match till end if the right-hand context is missing.

Comment: Looks like you may also split with `(?!\A)\s+(?=\d{3})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can omit the capture group and use a positive lookahead instead.

```
\b\d{3}\b.*?(?=\s+\d{3}\b)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Zef7rA/1)

If you also want to include the last match, you can add an alternation to assert the end of the string.

```
\b\d{3}\b.*?(?=\s+\d{3}\b|$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uTOWZF/1)